# SSL Offloading to Apache2 for Wordpress Site

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, wordpress, google-compute-engine, apache2

I have a WordPress site running on a Google Compute Engine instance and SSL used to be setup inside Apache.

Since SSL and image resizing was placing a lot of strain on that instance, I've setup a Google Compute Engine Load Balancer, setup SSL in the Load Balancer and enabled CDN.

On the Apache side I disabled the `*:443` config and left only the `*:80` config.The Load Balancer now accepts request on port 443 and points to the instance on port 80.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin info@mysite.com
        ServerName  mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com

        # Indexes + Directory Root.
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/htdocs/

        # Logfiles
        ErrorLog  /var/www/mysite/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/mysite/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This works, except that I'm getting Mixed Content errors on the site now since all the resources are still loading via HTTP.

I now tried to enable URL rewrites to see if I can get all the content to come back via https:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin info@mysite.com
        ServerName  mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com

        # Indexes + Directory Root.
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/htdocs/

        # Logfiles
        ErrorLog  /var/www/mysite/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/mysite/logs/access.log combined

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

As soon as I enable the RewriteEngine and rewrite the urls as above, I get infinite number of redirects.

I'm a bit rusty on the Apache side as I've been using NGINX almost exclusively over the last 5 years, any ideas on how to get WordPress to work properly on this setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there's nothing wrong with my setup, adding the following line in WordPress' `wp-config.php` fixes it

```
// force SSL
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Or if you want to run both http and https:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'){
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
}
```

Obviously removing the https redirects:

```
#        RewriteEngine on
#        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA,R=permanent]
```